# Spring Integration XMPP and File Transfer

Tags: xmpp, spring-integration

I need to transfer files to a user connected to a XMPP Server.

The file transfer is supported by Spring Integration XMPP? (The current release version is 4.1.6-RELEASE, the snapshot is 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT).

I succesfully send text messages using the XMPP Message Outbound Gateway using a configuration like this:

```
<int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundEventAdapter"
                    channel="outboundEventChannel"
                    xmpp-connection="testConnection"/>
```

Using this Outbound Gateway I'm not able to send files (only String and org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message payloads are supported)

Thanks in advance.

Massimo

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Integration XMPP module is fully based on the Smack library, so I'd be glad to hear from you or from anybody else who confirm and show us how to do that with Smack first of all.

And only after that we will be able to come with some `adaptation` from our perspective.

Please, refer to [Smack XMPP File Transfer](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-XMPP-File-Transfer) for more information.

From other side if you are able to come up with some solution on the matter you always can wrap it to the standard `<int:service-activator>` to make your application working.

Comment: Hi @artembilan,  thank you for your reply.  I found example code for XMPP File Transfer on this page: https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/filetransfer.html  My question was intended to check if the XMPP File Transfer is actually supported or not by Spring Integration  I suppose there's the need to make two new Channel Adapters to be added to the **Inbound Message Channel Adapter**, **Outbound Message Channel Adapter**, **Inbound Presence Message Channel Adapter** and **Outbound Presence Message Channel Adapter**. Is my guess correct?